# Having trouble initializing wordpress within plugin

Tags: plugins

I'm new to Wordpress plugins.  I've been asked to improve an existing plugin we have (make it more portable, etc).  When installing the plugin and trying to use it the first thing I get is a fatal error about a missing file.

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
```

My install is at /wp, so this immediately fails.  I'm having trouble figuring out the correct way to load or initialize wordpress within my plugin to give me access to the database connection, etc.  I assumed this would already be working.

From my brief searching on the topic people are recommending NOT including that file, but I haven't seen a good way to do it another way.  I've tried these approaches as well.

This fails since ABSPATH is not yet defined.

```
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-load.php' );
```

This fails since it's not yet defined.

```
get_home_path()
```

I'm using the latest version and a clean install.  The plugin I'm working with is probably a year or two old at least.

Any help would be great.

EDIT:

More specifically, the code wants to connect to the database to pull some info to display.

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;
$sql = "some query";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

But the require fails since the file doesn't exist at that location.  I just need to know how to include the file safely for any install.  I was assuming since Wordpress is loading the plugin that I would have access at that point to ABSPATH and get_home_path(), but that doesn't seem to be the case.

EDIT 2:

OK, looks like the plugin is adding functionality to the tinymce editor.  This code calls the problem file, webform-select.php, which needs to connect to the db, that's what the include is for.

```
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.tinyplugin', {
        init : function(ed, url){
            ed.addButton('tinyplugin', {
                title : 'title',
                cmd : 'command',
                image: url + "/images/icon.gif"
            });
            ed.addCommand('mceWebform', function() {
                ed.windowManager.open({
                        file : url + '/webform-select.php',
                        width : 420 + ed.getLang('example.delta_width', 0),
                        height : 315 + ed.getLang('example.delta_height', 0),
                        inline : 1
                });
            });
        },
    ...
```

Comment: this is difficult to answer without knowing the context of this code. the plugin is certainly doing things wrong if WordPress needs to be loaded by the plugin, it should be the other way around.

Comment: regarding your edit, how is the file that code is contained within loaded? is it requesting the php file directly via an ajax request? the answer you're looking for is how to successfully load `wp-load.php`, but the correct answer to your question is how to properly structure the plugin to eliminate the need to load that file.

Comment: Do you really need to load that file? There must be other option.

Comment: Ahh... maybe it is using ajax or just js.  See EDIT 2...  What's the appropriate way to account for that?